# Check that all symbols defined in static library

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

I built some static library with no errors.
When I tried to link it to some app I realized that some symbols is undefined inside library.

I want to get error on library building step not on app.

In other words

```
$ cat mylib.h
void foo();
$ cat mylib.c
#include "mylib.h"
// no foo() implementation here;
$ cat test.c 
#include "mylib.h"

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
$ gcc mylib.c -c
$ ar crf libmylib.a *.o
$ gcc test.c -lmylib -L.
/tmp/cc7201uP.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `foo'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I want to get error at one of those step

```
$ gcc mylib.c -c
$ ar crf libmylib.a *.o
```

Is it possible, and what is good practice for such situations?

**Updated:**
I tried 
`$ nm --undefined-only *.a`
output is :

```
mylib.o:
```

It's little bit strange for me. I expect something like `foo()` inside output.

Answer (score 2):

A static library is just a bunch of `.o` files and those are expected to have undefined references. No linking is involved when producing a `.a` from `.o` files.

You can run `nm --undefined-only libmylib.a` and that produces a list of all undefined symbols. That list will include all the symbols you use from C standard library because, again, no linking is involved when producing `.a` files.

Comment: So there is no way to check that you don't miss something inside it?

Comment: @StepanLoginov You can run `nm --undefined-only *.a`.